# basic android socket communication

Tags: android, sockets

I tried to build a connection between computer and mobile phone. 
When I run PC_Client and phone_Server, both of them can work. But when I run the entire program, it didn't show the data. And when I click them in emulator, it said server is stopped.

Any help will be appreciated!

In PC_Client,

```
package com.example.violet.server;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

 class PC_Client
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException
    {
        //Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1" , 30000);
        Socket socket = new Socket("10.1.1.6" , 2000);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        String line = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("from server：" + line);
        br.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

In phone_Server

```
package com.example.violet.server;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
class phone_Server
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException
    {
        InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("Ip is"+address.getHostAddress());
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2000);
        while (true)
        {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ps.println("Hello！");
            ps.close();
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

In manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.violet.server">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Project Structure:

[image]

Emulator :

[image]

Comment: You need to post your logcat, and you need to provide all evidence here, not via links. Don't post pictures of text: post the text. All this should be edited into your question.

Comment: Please show and tell how and where you are starting your server.